Configuring @thmnoarg and @thmoptarg to change the indentation of the text inside a theorem in thmtools
In my LaTeX document, I want my "Proof" command to indent the material in the proof. So I used the following code to do so:
\documentclass[openany, 10.5pt]{book}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Proof Style
\declaretheoremstyle[
title=proof, headfont=\lmromansc\fontsize{10pt}{0}, bodyfont=\normalfont, numbered=no, headpunct={ }, 
spaceabove=12pt, spacebelow=18pt]{proof}
\declaretheorem[style=proof]{Proof}

\makeatletter
\preto\Proof{%
  \patchcmd\cref@thmnoarg
    {\trivlist}
    {\list{}{\leftmargin\setlength{20pt}}}
    {}{}%
  \patchcmd\cref@thmoptarg
    {\trivlist}
    {\list{}{\leftmargin\setlength{20pt}}}
    {}{}%
  \patchcmd\thmt@original@endProof{\endtrivlist}{\endlist}{}{}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{Proof}
\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[2]
\end{Proof}
\end{document}

However, it has changed the vertical space between paragraphs and removed the indent at the beginning of a new paragraph. How do I fix this?

Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example, starting with \documentclass and ending with \end{document}, instead of a code snippet.

@JoséCarlosSantos Is this sufficient?

Yes, it is sufficient.

You have several errors and are missing a few parameters.
I also suggest how to avoid code duplication.
Note that the syntax is \setlength{\leftmargin}{20pt} and not
\leftmargin\setlength{20pt}

which is meaningless. Inside lists, LaTeX uses \listparindent; you also want to zero \parsep.
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Proof Style
\declaretheoremstyle[
  title=proof,
  headfont=\scshape,
  bodyfont=\normalfont,
  numbered=no,
  headpunct={ }, 
  spaceabove=12pt,
  spacebelow=18pt
]{proof}
\declaretheorem[style=proof]{Proof}

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\prooflist@}{%
  \list{}{%
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{20pt}%
    \setlength{\listparindent}{\parindent}%
    \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}%
  }%
}

\preto\Proof{%
  \patchcmd\cref@thmnoarg{\trivlist}{\prooflist@}{}{}%
  \patchcmd\cref@thmoptarg{\trivlist}{\prooflist@}{}{}%
  \patchcmd\thmt@original@endProof{\endtrivlist}{\endlist}{}{}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[42]

\begin{Proof}
\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[2]
\end{Proof}

\end{document}


Note: I removed the mysterious \lmromansc\fontsize{10pt}{0} and also the inexistent 10.5pt option.

Thank you so much! It's hard to write errorless code when you're learning from snippets of other people's code, so I appreciate you noting these errors. As for the 10.5pt font, you're quite right. I hadn't noticed it had no affect on the size of the text.
